# InitState is not working in my child widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a parent widget and a child widget which does not hold any state.

From my understanding, initState function will be called every time before the page is rendered (Correct me if i am wrong).

So in my case, when i render my parent widget, the initState function in my child widget is not working.

Can someone please explain why this is the case, and what is the right way to do it?

My code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => 
  _HomePageState();
  }

 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
    int _balanceIndex = 0;
    List<HomeBalanceCardModel> _balanceCardInfos =
       HomeBalanceCardInfos.getMockData();

    _onBalancePageChange(index, _) {
     setState(() {
     _balanceIndex = index;
    });
  }


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      centerTitle: false,
      pinned: true,
      floating: false,
      snap: false,
      primary: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      title: HomeAppBar(title: "Banking"),
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: HomeBalanceCarousel(
        balanceCardInfos: _balanceCardInfos,
        onPageChanged: _onBalancePageChange,
      )),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child:
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20), child: HomeAdBanner()),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child:LoanList(),
    )
  ],
));
```

}

My child Widget:

```
class LoanList extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoanList({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoanListState createState() => _LoanListState();
  } 

class _LoanListState extends State<LoanList> {

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   print('running init state');
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      _buildTab(),
      _buildList(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html "initState method - Called when this object is inserted into the tree. The framework will call this method exactly once for each State object it creates."

Comment: Noted. BTW Instead of using initState, what method should i use?

Comment: to achieve what exactly? `build` should be called every time the widget is re-rendered, but you shouldn't be doing anything in build other than rendering the widget.

Comment: Is this question answered now? If yes, it'd be great for the answerer to post the answer officially and for the person asking the question to actually accept that answer so we can close this question. thank you